# is HTTPS mandatory to use google on Recaptcha? Can it be used on "http" sites?

Tags: recaptcha

I would like to use a recaptcha on my webform.

The google docs here (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) say this -

"The script must be loaded using the HTTPS protocol and can be included from any point on the page without restriction."

Does that mean that my site has to be HTTPS for it to work? Is there a way to use Recaptcha without HTTPS?

Thanks

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Construct the Google verification API request link.
    $params = array();
    $params['secret'] = '______________PRIVATE KEY_________.'; // Secret key
    if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $params['response'] = urlencode($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    }
    $params['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $params_string = http_build_query($params);
    $requestURL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?' . $params_string;

    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set some options
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $requestURL,
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    $response = @json_decode($response, true);

    if ($response["success"] == true) {
        echo '<h3 class="alert alert-success">Login Successful</h3>';
    } else {
        echo '<h3 class="alert alert-danger">Login failed</h3>';
    }
}
```

I've tried this code in PHP on my mailer.php file but it's not working.

So now I'm assuming that it's an HTTPS problem?

Comment: It's 2019, there is no reason not to use HTTPS everywhere. Why not simply use it?

Comment: My server charges $50 for a dedicated IP and a certificate? thoughts? edit - the site I'm building won't actually generate any income.